# Finding element using attribute ignoring case

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Is there any way to find element using an attribute which must not be case sensitive?

Think that, I want to find element by a title like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[title='This is a Test Title']")).sendKeys("Test");
```

But change in the title text won't affect my `WebElement`.

Comment: Try the css3 selector [attr*=value], this selects all elements that contain the substring of `value`, in your case try `input[title="itle"]`, a small work around for the case sensitiveness :)

Comment: Sorry @VladNeacsu, I meant entire title text (This is a Test Title).

Comment: I've just tested. In HTML there are some attributes which are case insensitive (examples are IDs and Classes but those make sense), but unfortunately `title` is not :( https://jsfiddle.net/8ou7aw3a/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can xpath to achieve this. look at below example.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[translate(@title, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'this is my title']")).sendKeys("Test");
```

The above xpath will convert all uppercase letters from title to lower case and check if it is equal to given value.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But, single quote should be used for lowercase letters.
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[translate(@title, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'this is my title']")).sendKeys("Test");

Comment: Is there any CSS way to do the same thing?  @Sudharsan

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to locate the element ignoring the case sensitivity of the attribute values using the character i or I after the value.

"input[title='This is a Test Title'] i")

you can refer : http://pragmatictestlabs.com/2021/01/05/mastering-css-for-selenium-test-automation-2/

Answer (score 0):

I found that, css-selectors ignore the case. So, maybe you can select some parent element first, then select the target element by the parent element.

Answer (score -3):

**First you select element**

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[title='This is a Test Title']"));
```

**Second you get sub element**

```
WebElement subElement=element.findElement(By.tagName("Your Tag Here").attr("Your Attribute"));
```

**Finally**

```
subElement.sendKey("Test");
```